# compare two list of dictonary with different order in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dict which I need to compare but dict in different order so I am not sure what is the correct way to do it.

l1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]

l2 = [{'b': '2'}, {'a': '1'}]

result should be true when I compare l1 and l2 as both have same dictionaries in their respective list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
l1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]

l2 = [{'b': '2'}, {'a': '1'}]

if (all(item in l1 for item in l2) and all(item in l2 for item in l1)):
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by list comprehension:

```
dict_1 = {"a": '1', "b": '2'}
dict_2 = {"b": '2', "a": '1'}
res = all((dict_2.get(k) == v for k, v in dict_1.items()))
print(res)
```

Output:
True

Answer (score 1):

Sort the dict in the list and compare, we can get it

```
l1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]
l2 = [{'b': '2'}, {'a': '1'}]

list_1 = sorted(l1, key=lambda k: list(k.values())[0])
list_2 = sorted(l2, key=lambda k: list(k.values())[0])

if list_1 == list_2:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting edge case if duplicates are not ruled out:

E.g. `[ A, A, A, B ]` compared with `[B, B, A]`

All items from list1 are present in list2 and all items from list2 are present in list1. For me they are not equal, one list is not the same as the other list shuffled.

The function below should be able to deal with that case. It returns true, only if the lists contents correspond one-to-one.

The function creates a shallow copy of the second list and each time a match is found for an item from the first list, it gets removed (by replacing with the `void` sentinel for simplicity).

```
def ls_compare(ls1, ls2):
    if len(ls1) != len(ls2):
        # don't waste time
        return False

    void = object()
    ls2copy = ls2.copy() 
    for item in ls1:
        try:
            in2 = ls2copy.index(item)
        except ValueError:
            # item not found
            return False
        ls2copy[in2] = void

    return all(item is void for item in ls2copy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort the dictionaries in each list by converting them to strings and sorting the strings, then compare it like following:

```py
l1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]
l2 = [{'b': '2'}, {'a': '1'}]

l1_sorted = sorted([str(d) for d in l1])
l2_sorted = sorted([str(d) for d in l2])

result=True if l1_sorted==l2_sorted else False

print(result)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in linear time complexity, you can convert each sub-dict to a frozenset of item tuples, convert each list to a set of such frozensets, so that you can efficiently compare the two lists of dicts by comparing the two converted sets of frozensets instead:

```
from operator import eq

print(eq(*(set(frozenset(map(tuple, d.items())) for d in l) for l in (l1, l2))))
```

Given your sample input, this outputs:

```
True
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PassionateUnwrittenSimulation